# How to encode content to send them via jquery to a php file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a form to a PHP file via jQuery. The problem is, that the content, which has to be sent to the PHP file, contains slashes (`/`) since there is BBcode inside.
So I tried the following:

```
$.ajax( 
    { 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "create.php", 
        data: "content=" + encodeURIComponent(content),
        cache: false,
        success: function(message)
        {   
            $("#somediv").html(message);
        }               
  });
```

In the PHP file I use `rawurldecode()` to decode the content and get my BBcodes back which I can then transform into HTML. The problem is as soon as I put the `encodeURIComponent()` it will output: `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]`

What does that mean, where is my mistake?

Comment: So, let me clarify: `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]` is what is contained in `#somediv`?  That sounds crazy to me and that's what your question implies, so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: can you show what is represented by the `content` variable?

Comment: the content variable should contain the content of the textfield with the ID "content".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package your data as an object literal, and and let jquery worry about the dirty details:

```
// javascript
 $.post(
      "create.php",
      {
           content: "here is my content / slashes included."
      },
      function( message ) {
           $("#somediv").html( message );
      }
 )


 ///////////////////////////////////////////////

 // php
 $formData = $_POST["content"];
 echo $formData;
 // yields: here is my content / slashes included.
```

Comment: And of course, as the other folks have said, make sure you've got the actual content of the element in question when you prepare to post(), *not* the element itself.

Comment: Now its the same thing as at the very beginning. If my content is: [b]something[b] it is ok, but if it is [b]something[/b] it doesnt show anything.

This is my code now, should be working or not?
`var content = $("#content").val();
        $.post( 
  "create_preview.php",
        { 
            type: "POST", 
            content: content
  },
  function(message)
  { 
   $("#previewdiv").html(message);     
  }
  )`

Comment: Could you post the relevant portion of your php script?

Comment: My php is just: `echo $bbcode->parse_bbcode($_POST["content"]);`

Comment: What's parse_bbcode() actually doing? Is it stripping out stuff enclosed by tags? What's the resulting output if you post a string like "<b>something within tag</b> alongside something outside of tag"?

Comment: Omg now it is working with ur code! Guess what was the problem: I call the function in the content textfield with onchange. And I have buttons adding bbcode to the textfield. The problem is that adding bbcode to the textfield via mouse click seems not to count as "onchange". In fact I have to put the bbcode inside and then add another letter for the function to get called. So now it works, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

your `content` variable is a textarea element, not the text inside the textarea (if that's what you're looking for, since you didn't state what `content` is)

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but the value of your variable `content` appears to be an HTML element as opposed to the contents of that HTML element.

Elsewhere in your code you may have something like:

```
var content = $("selector");
```

...but it should be:

```
var content = $("selector").val();
```

Can't tell for sure without seeing the rest of your code, but that's what it seems like to me.

Comment: content is the ID of the textfield. Ive put var content = $("#content").text(); in the script, now the weird message doesnt appear anymore but there is no output at all

Comment: use $("#content").val() instead.

Comment: Now its the same thing as at the very beginning. If my content is: [b]something[b] it is ok, but if it is [b]something[/b] it doesnt show anything